# How can I prove the following equation.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For $0\le{}x\le1$ and for $0\le{}y\le1$, $f(x, y)$ satisfies that, for each $x$, $f(x, y)$ is an integrable function of $y$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial{}f(x, y)}{\partial{}x}$ is a bounded function of $(x, y)$.

Show that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial{}f(x, y)}{\partial{}x}$ is a measurable function of $y$ for each $x$ and $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1f(x, y)dy=\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x, y)dy$$

---

Actually I obtained a solution of this problem on internet. However, it is hard for me to understand. Please let me know how to prove this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed ($x,y)$,
$$
\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h.
$$
The Newton quotients are measurable (because translations, differences, and products by a number are measurable), so the partial derivative is a pointwise limit of a sequence (taking a sequence $h_n$ with $h_n\to0$) of measurable functions and is thus measurable.

Now fix a sequence $\{h_n\}$ with $h_n\to0$. Note that, by the Mean Value Theorem, 
$$
\left|\frac{f(x+h_n,y)-f(x,y)}{h_n}\right|=\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(c,y)\right|\leq M
$$
for some upper bound $M$ of the partial derivative. So we can apply Dominated Convergence for the sequence $$\frac{f(x+h_n,y)-f(x,y)}{h_n}$$ bounded by the function $g(x,y)=M$ (which is integrable because our region is bounded).

Then, since the sequence $\{h_n\}$ is arbitrary$^1$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dy
&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^1f(x+h_n,y)\,dy-\int_0^1f(x,y)\,dy}{h_n}\\ \ \\
&=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x+h_n,y)-f(x,y)}{h_n}\,dy\\ \ \\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dy
\end{align}

---

1. Here we use that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=L$ for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\to x_0$.

Comment: Can you explain why the Newton quotients are measurable with more detail? Also, the last $h_n$ should be removed in the formula that $\displaystyle\left|\frac{f(x+h_n, y) - f(x, y)}{h_n}\right| = \left|\frac{\partial{}f}{\partial{}x}(c, y) h_n\right|$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Edited. Not sure what else there is to explain: if $f(x,y)$ is measurable, so is $f(x+h,y)$; so is $f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)$; so is $(f(x+h,y)-f(x,y))/h$.